# Does anyone know how to get the Bing Search Toolbar to work again in ArcGIS 10 Business Analyst after the SP2 install?

Tags: business, arcgis-10.0

I just updated my ArcGIS Business Analyst with the Server Pack 2 upgrade and now the Bing Search Toolbar does not work.  Is anyone else having this problem and if so do you know of a way to fix it?  Note: I would and I am sure anyone else with this problem would prefer a solution that does not require uninstalling SP2.

Comment: All i know my Bing Search quit yesterday and sends you everywhere except the site you're looking for!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's looks to be a bug introduced...

I would keep an eye on your esri forum post:

http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/35147-Bing-Search-Bar-No-Longer-Works-After-SP2-install.

And however an esri staff member will reply. May require a patch for the service pack 2.

Comment: Don't rely on an Esri employee seeing a post in the Esri forums; if you pay maintenance, contact technical support and open an incident. I don't see anything in the incident database yet.

Comment: The speed of ESRI UK Support is very poor even when paid 10+ years of support - even the automated email can take 3 days to be sent.